# `DoCheck` - throw error as `forEachRemoveItem' of null`

Tags: angular

I am trying to reproduce the `DoCheck` angular future. But I am getting an error says as : `forEachRemoveItem' of null` - which I am not able to understand. Any one please help me to figure out the issue?

here is my code :

```
import { Component, Input, DoCheck, IterableDiffers } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
  selector:'numbers',
  template:`
    {{numbers}} <br/>
    <p *ngFor="let change of changes">{{change}}</p>
  `,
  styles: ['p{padding:0;margin:0}']
})

export class NumbersComponent implements DoCheck {
  @Input('numbers') numbersArray:Array<string>;
  changes:Array<string>=[];
  differ;

  constructor(private differs:IterableDiffers){
    this.differ = differs.find([]).create(null);
  }

  ngDoCheck(){

    const differences = this.differ.diff(this.numbersArray);

    if(differences){
      if(differences.forEachAddItem){
        differences.forEachAddedItem((item) =>{
          if((item) && (item.item)){
            this.changes.push('added', item.item);
          }
        })
      }
    }

     if(differences.forEachRemoveItem){
      differences.forEachRemovedItem((item) =>{
        if((item) && (item.item)){
          this.changes.push('removed' + item.item);
        }
      })
    }
  }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  numbers = '';
}
```

if requires more details, let me know.

my template :

```
Enter Array (comma-separated): 
<input [(ngModel)]="numbers" (onModelChange)="onModelChange"/> <br/>
<numbers [numbers]="numbers.split(',')"></numbers>
```

Comment: `differences` is `null` What do you want to understand?

Comment: @yurzui - my inputs should be populated, but getting errors

Comment: Check your example. Collection is populated but there is no changes on the second ngDoCheck

Comment: You should write  `if (changes)` Just look at angular source code https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/common/src/directives/ng_for_of.ts#L151 But you only check it for `forEachAddItem`

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-v99sxv?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: @yurzui - I am not getting any output populated..

Comment: You're changing the same item in array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**app.component.html**

First, replace

```
<numbers [numbers]="numbers.split(',')"></numbers>
```

with

```
<numbers [numbers]="numbers.split('')"></numbers>
```

**numbers.component.ts**

Then wrap all logic in `if`

```
const differences = this.differ.diff(this.numbersArray);

if(differences){
  ... some logic..
}
```

And finally you made typos

```
if(differences.forEachAddItem){
                        ||
                        \/
               forEachAddedItem


if(differences.forEachRemoveItem){
                           ||
                           \/
                  forEachRemovedItem){
```

**[Stackblitz Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vqf1g1?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts)**